# Can't add products to cart - WooCommerce eCommerce plungin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Every time I try to add a product to cart, even when the the size has been selected and there is a given price, I get the message "Please choose product options…"

site url is http://imysecy.com/nvi/product/nest-rattan-chair/

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a price for both Variations? Otherwise when you chose a variation the price will be overwritten by NULL.

Comment: And WooCommerce > System Status does not give any Information?

Comment: Ok it seems to be a Problem of the Theme. Your Theme Author has to update the template file to fix it. Or the quick solution is to delete this file from your theme directory:

/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php

WooCommerce will use the new bundled template file which will make it work again. When your theme developer updates your theme you should check if it actually works as that will overwrite this change again.

Comment: i have updated woocommerce plungin. but i am getting same issue.

Comment: Thought so ;-) You should try what I wrote above... Back up and delete the file. I'm pretty sure thats gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a custom theme make sure you call wp_head() and wp_footer() functions in your template files. Those functions will make sure the necessary js files are included to make the woocommerce-plugin function correctly.

Javascript is needed to make woocommerce do it's thing. As a test you can disable Javascript (in chrome devtools -> settings -> disable javascript), you'll get the same error (Please choose product options…).

Btw, a javascript error might stop or hinder js execution, don't forget to check your console in devtools now and then ... uhm, I mean all the time ... :)